# Editing the elements of a list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

My question is kind of a two part question.

If you are given a list

```
numbers = [10, 20, 30, 100]
```

and you wish to edit every element inside the list by adding 10 to each element. How would I go about doing this? And are you able to do this without creating a separate list?

Similarly, if you are given a list such as:

```
words = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi']
```

and wish to change every letter h inside the list to another letter say 'r' would it be a similar algorithm as the last?

Answer (score 3):

Because you said you don't want to create a new list, you can't use list comprehension or map function as @gcandal suggested. You can try this instead.

```
def update_list(l, fn):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = fn(l[i])

update_list(numbers, lambda a: a + 10)
update_list(words, lambda s: s.replace('h', 'r'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by applying [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
numbers_plus_ten = map(lambda number: number + 10, numbers)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
numbers_plus_ten = [number + 10 for number in numbers]
```